# ASP.NET 2.0 stored procedure delete not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

I have an event that fires on a button click that calls a stored procedure that deletes the selected row from the database.

In debugging this I have already hard coded the stored procedure with an id to make sure the delete was working on SQL side so I wont post the stored procedure. I also went into my page and on selecting the record to delete made sure that the hidden field was being set to the id of the record.

When I click I see the post back occur so I see the button firing, and it may be something small and stupid with my code or a permissions issue I am not aware of or where to look for.

The parameter for the stored procedure is an integer, and I am not hitting the catch or throwing errors of any kind the data just is not being deleted.

Thanks for any help on this issue as always it is much appreciated.

This is the code that fires when the button is clicked.

```
if (isAdmin)
{
    SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(server);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("STOREDPROCNAME", cnx);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VARIABLEFORPROC", Convert.ToInt16(hiddenfield1.Value.ToString()));

    try
    {
       cnx.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cnx.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw new Exception("Error executing MyProcedureName.", ex);
    }
}

fillDataGrids();
```

Comment: and isAdmin is explicitly set to true for the time being I have not added that functionality yet.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and verified that the hidden field value you are using as the parameter is a valid value?

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Profiler to ensure that the query is actually reaching SQL Server?

Comment: Run the sql profile in Management studio and see what query it exactly passes..

Comment: The above code doesn't seems to have anything wrong. I think you should show the storedproc text to have a complete understanding of the problem

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Jon pointed out that SQL INT maps to C# int32 I was converting to int 16 when i changed the conversion it worked. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The SQL Int type maps to the C# Int32 type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx).  It's possible that you're getting data loss during your conversion.  Try replacing

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VARIABLEFORPROC", Convert.ToInt16(hiddenfield1.Value.ToString()));
```

with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VARIABLEFORPROC", Convert.ToInt32(hiddenfield1.Value.ToString()));
```

Comment: Chalk one up for small and stupid. Thanks Jon that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

you must to try the stored procedure accuracy in SQL
after than try it on a transaction and log the exception on the DB
you must be sure where is the error happening